# JFreeChart: how to set the duration/period of a candle?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

Is it possible to set the duration/period of a single OHLCItem on a CandlestickChart?

What I'm trying to achieve is the possibility of merging two candles together into one OHLCItem. But the problem is that I can only set a point in time on the X Axis where the candle should be drawn, while the merged candle should take the space of the two merged candles.

Is there any way to achieve this? Hopefully the screenshot better explains what I'm aiming at:

[image]

Currently I'm merging candles with the following code, but this just replaces one of the items at this item's millisecond:

```
private static OHLCItem getMergedItem(int i, OHLCItem clickedItem, OHLCItem neighbourItem) {
    double high;
    double low;

    if(clickedItem.getLowValue() >= neighbourItem.getLowValue()) {
        low = neighbourItem.getLowValue();
    }
    else {
        low = clickedItem.getLowValue();
    }
    if(clickedItem.getHighValue() >= neighbourItem.getHighValue()) {
        high = clickedItem.getHighValue();
    }
    else {
        high = neighbourItem.getHighValue();
    }

    if(i == 1) {
        return new OHLCItem(clickedItem.getPeriod(), neighbourItem.getOpenValue(), high, low, clickedItem.getCloseValue());
    }
    else {
        return new OHLCItem(neighbourItem.getPeriod(), clickedItem.getOpenValue(), high, low, neighbourItem.getCloseValue());
    }
}
```